# How can I display target path in a Typescript watch message?

Tags: bash, typescript, terminal

When I run `tsc --watch` the terminal clears and I see:

```
[15:43:52] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[15:44:14] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

I'm working within a monorepo that has multiple packages and hence multiple watch tasks. It gets confusing as to which one's which. Currenly I have to manually label terminal sessions.

I'd like to add some indication as to what path is currently being watched to this message. Is that possible?

Comment: Does `--diagnostics` or `--extendedDiagnostics` show what you want? You can also `--listFiles`, although that might be a bit much in a bigger project. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html.

Comment: Ah sadly not. `--diagnostics` gives way too much info and `--listFiles` gives all the node_modules dependencies so you end up with absolute paths to that dir at the root of the monorepo printed. Thanks for the suggestion though! Hadn't seen those flags before

Comment: ....ah `--listEmittedFiles`  is pretty close though actually! :-D

Comment: You could also try `--preserveWatchOutput` to prevent the screen getting cleared.

Answer (score 0):

`--listEmittedFiles` is the one, as pointed in the direction of above by @jonrsharpe. Thanks!